# json помогите новичку

Tags: python, json

```
import json
```

что то я закипел обьясните новичку че не так то

```
AIRPORT_URL = 'http://api.travelpayouts.com/data/ru/airports.json'

json_data = requests.get(AIRPORT_URL).json()


parsed_data  = json.loads(json_data)

print(parsed_data)
```

---

вобще надо в этом json найти code":"MRV и передать в переменную "name":"Минеральные Воды"

Comment: А вы запустите и посмотрите на ошибку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лови   // Ответ на дополнительный вопрос

```
import requests

AIRPORT_URL = 'http://api.travelpayouts.com/data/ru/airports.json'

json_data = requests.get(AIRPORT_URL).json()

for findMRV in json_data:
    if findMRV['code'] == 'MRV':
        MRV = findMRV['name_translations']['en']
        print(MRV)
        break
```

Если надо именно на русском из этого же массива:

```
import requests

AIRPORT_URL = 'http://api.travelpayouts.com/data/ru/airports.json'

json_data = requests.get(AIRPORT_URL).json()

for findMRV in json_data:
    if findMRV['code'] == 'MRV':
        MRV = findMRV['name']
        print(MRV)
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

@alex smolyakov Не переживайте ) Вам надо вывести массив?

```
import requests

AIRPORT_URL = 'http://api.travelpayouts.com/data/ru/airports.json'

json_data = requests.get(AIRPORT_URL).json()

print(json_data)
```